# Make caret (cursor) stop blinking

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I make the cursor in a TextBox stop blinking in WPF?

I have already tried to a `MouseDown` event on the parent, with one action, `this.Focus();`, which does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have achieved this with [HideCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-hidecaret) Method. However, since the WPF application cannot provide you handle for the TextBox Control (it only provides handle for Window), we cannot use HideCaret.

However, we could [emulate](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox) the effect using WPF. The first step to achieve this would be disable the actual Caret. This can be done by changing the Color to transparent.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" CaretBrush="Transparent" />
```

The Next step involve using a Canvas and Border to emulate the Cursor.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" CaretBrush="Transparent" />
    <Canvas>
        <Border x:Name="Caret" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="1" Height="15" Background="Black"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

You need to ensure the Canvas overlap the Textbox

And in code-behind

```
txtName.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => MoveCustomCaret();
txtName.LostFocus += (sender, e) => Caret.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
txtName.GotFocus += (sender, e) => Caret.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Where MoveCustomCaret is defined as

```
    private void MoveCustomCaret()
    {
        var caretLocation = txtName.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(txtName.CaretIndex).Location;

        if (!double.IsInfinity(caretLocation.X))
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Caret, caretLocation.X);
        }

        if (!double.IsInfinity(caretLocation.Y))
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(Caret, caretLocation.Y);
        }
    }
```

**Sample**

[image]